# Helm Download Source Package

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I'm trying to download the source tar.gz of a package.  Doing a 'helm dependency build' generates no output and I'm not finding the package.  I need to open it up and look at the source files and entrypoint.sh file that are not in the charts.  Anyone know what command I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really possible as you've described it.

A Helm chart only contains a (templated) set of Kubernetes manifests, and these only reference `image:` by name.  Helm on its own doesn't keep track what Docker images might be used.  Further, in general, a Docker image doesn't necessarily include its source, and in general there's not a way to get this back.  (Well-packaged Go applications might only contain a compiled binary and nothing else in their images.)

In principle you could start with something like

```bash
helm template . | grep image:
```

to find the list of referenced images, but there's no standard way to get those images' original sources.